# Update pandas series value based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of strings. I want to do something like this:

```
for item in series:
    if '!' in item:
        series[item] = item.split('!')[0]
```

Basically, if there's a '!' in the string, replace it with the part before the '!'. The code doesn't seem to change the series at all. How to do the conditional replace properly?

Answer (score 5):

I think condition is not necessary if use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
s = pd.Series(['sss!dd','sdsd', 'aa!p'])

s = s.str.split('!').str[0]
0     sss
1    sdsd
2      aa
dtype: object
```

But if need condition add [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
s = s.mask(s.str.contains('!'), s.str.split('!').str[0])
print (s)
0     sss
1    sdsd
2      aa
dtype: object
```

Comment: I also need to strip them of trailing space in-place.?

Comment: Use `s = s.str.strip().str.split('!').str[0]`if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Using @jezrael's data set:

```
In [74]: s
Out[74]:
0    sss!dd
1      sdsd
2      aa!p
dtype: object

In [75]: s = s.str.replace(r'\!.*','')

In [76]: s
Out[76]:
0     sss
1    sdsd
2      aa
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

**Option 1**
You can also use `pd.Series.replace` with the `regex=True` parameter

```
s.replace('(.*)!.*', r'\1', regex=True)

0     sss
1    sdsd
2      aa
dtype: object
```

**Option 2**
You can use `numpy.core.defchararray.split`

```
pd.Series(
    [x[0] for x in np.core.defchararray.split(s.values.astype(str), '!')],
    s.index
)

0     sss
1    sdsd
2      aa
dtype: object
```